# Draw two buttons in a Row using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-button, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I want to have two buttons in a `Row`, just as in the picture, but in my code I set a specific horizontalArrangment and it wouldn't look good on other devices

```
Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(170.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                text = "Send Email",
                style = TextStyle(fontSize = 15.sp)
            )
        }
        Button(
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                text = "Call",
                style = TextStyle(fontSize = 15.sp)
            )
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween`:

Something like:

```
 Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Button( onClick = { /*TODO*/ }){
            Text(
                text = "Send Email",
                style = TextStyle(fontSize = 15.sp)
            )
        }
        Button( onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text(
                text = "Call",
                style = TextStyle(fontSize = 15.sp)
            )
        }
    }
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: What if we add another button in the middle; how can we ensure that the first is START, second is in the CENTER and the third is to the END?